# How to add items to ListBox or another control from XML? ASP.Net(C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-xml

I have XML file with the following structure:

```
<rule ID="16" Attribute="Savvy" Parametr="">
      <body>
        <term Operation="AND">
          <IF_ID>8</IF_ID>
          <Ratio>=</Ratio>
          <IF_Value>impossible</IF_Value>
        </term>
        <term Operation="OR">
          <IF_ID>9</IF_ID>
          <Ratio>=</Ratio>
          <IF_Value>yes</IF_Value>
        </term>
        <term Operation="AND">
          <IF_ID>8</IF_ID>
          <Ratio>!=</Ratio>
          <IF_Value>impossible</IF_Value>
        </term>
        <term>
          <IF_ID>9</IF_ID>
          <Ratio>=</Ratio>
          <IF_Value>no</IF_Value>
        </term>
      </body>
      <value>normal savvy</value>
    </rule>
```

I need to add it to Listbox and get 1 row:

```
8 = impossible AND 9 = yes OR 8 != impossible AND 9 = no - normal savvy
```

Comment: And what's your question or problem? How did you try to achieve your goal?

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: I don't know how to get attributes from elements and put them on right place

Comment: Did you even bother searching? http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=Xml+read+attributes+c%23&aq=f&aqi=g-v1g-j4g-b4&aql=&oq=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to know how to read an attribute via XDocument it is as simple as doing `xElement.Attribute("Operation")`

Now to actually get the string structure you want it all you need to do is loop through your terms and append them to a string.

```
var xDocument = XDocument.Parse(x);
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var xElement in xDocument.Descendants("term"))
{
    var operationValue = xElement.Attribute("Operation") == null ? string.Empty : xElement.Attribute("Operation").Value;
    stringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0} {1} {2} {3} ", 
                                    xElement.Element("IF_ID").Value, 
                                    xElement.Element("Ratio").Value,
                                    xElement.Element("IF_Value").Value,
                                    operationValue);
}
stringBuilder.AppendFormat("- {0}", xDocument.Descendants("value").First().Value);
```

This assumes that you will have a value for each element and there is only one `<rule/>`.  Null checks would be needed to make it correct for each element.

> 8 = impossible AND 9 = yes OR 8 !=
>   impossible AND 9 = no  - normal savvy

Now how this relates to a listbox I am not sure and might require a bit more detail?

```
var item = new ListItem(stringBuilder.ToString());
listBox.Items.Add(item);
```

???